# Returning only certain properties of a large object?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a large object composed of many different properties. I am manipulating this object with four different functions. Each function returns the object. Here is a very short version of my setup:

```
public class myproject
{
    //many attributes
}

public myproject FunctionOne()
{
    //do some logic.
    //return myproject but only properties 4,5,6
}
public myproject FunctionTwo()
{
    //do some logic.
    //return myproject but only properties 1,2,3
}
public myproject FunctionThree()
{
    //do some logic.
    //return myproject but only properties 1,4,7
}
public myproject FunctionFour()
{
    //do some logic.
    //return myproject but only properties 3,2,5
}
```

So the issue is, when I return my object, I only want to have certain properties available in that return. Sort of as if I was returning a custom object that was dynamically created simply for that purpose.

What options do I have to accomplish this?

Comment: You could define an interface which has only those properties and your `myproject` implements those interfaces; `FunctionOne` might return the object as that subset interface. This won't prevent the caller from subsequently casting to `myobject` (or the other interfaces) and then accessing the properties if that's an issue.

Comment: It's a strange request. Mind sharing some context for why you need this behavior? There may be a better way.

Comment: why do you need to do this.  Knowing why would help us in providing a suitable answer

Comment: I'm creating a web api, and we pull information from our database into a c# object, and use that information to return JSON based on the function called. The issue is that there is a lot of data in those objects that should not be seen unless specifically asked for in the appropriate function so I wanted the ability to only return partial versions of the whole object.

Comment: @proseidon Just to confirm: Is this to reduce the data size, to reduce the visibility, or both? If you're serializing it, you'll have to have a concrete class at some point with the data, but I guess you want to avoid writing DTO classes for each return type.

Comment: @MatthewWatson mainly to reduce visability. Someone calls a function and only needs several properties returned to them, not an entire object, because most of that data is irrelevant to them. However, that data is still possibly relevant in OTHER functions, hence why I am not just creating a smaller object; all properties are used, just spread out among different functions

Comment: @proseidon Then would it be acceptible to write several different interfaces, one for each "view" (which could have overlapping properties)? Then you could just return the appropriate interface, via `return this`. Won't work for serializing over a web call, but you could perform such tricks at the other end perhaps. (If it sounds possible I could write more details in an answer - but only if you're interested ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson unfortunately I do not control the other end, these apis are being used by various different people in their own programs and I have no idea what they are; I'm just trying to return them the json data that they request

Comment: @proseidon Ah, ok. Then I think your best bet is to write DTO classes just to return the appropriate properties. It's more work, but at least it's bound to work.

Comment: I agree with Matthew: define dedicated DTO return types for each method. The fact that some of those DTO properties happen to map to properties in this `myproject` is coincidental. If third parties are consuming your service, then you should try to make sure any implementation details are fully abstracted. This way if you subsequently break `myproject` into several other objects, you still construct a DTO to return to the consumers and they don't care _how_ you did it. They just care that the DTO _contract_ is maintained. (implementation details like this are trival to maintain anyway)

Comment: Just to clarify, you should create a _solid and stable data contract_ for your service; that's the important part to maintain long term. How you go about constructing the DTOs internally within the server is _easy_ and then frees you to do whatever you want.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Okay, I understand why I would use DTOs as the most proper solution. Thank you for the further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using REST and return JSON you might as well do something like this:

WebApi calls:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetOne()
{
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
        FunctionOne());
}
public HttpResponseMessage GetTwo()
{
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
        FunctionTwo());
}
```

Logic:

```
public dynamic FunctionOne()
{
    //do some logic.
    //return myproject but only properties 4,5,6
    return new {property4 = "abc", property5 = "xyz", property6 = "123"};
}
public dynamic FunctionTwo()
{
    //do some logic.
    //return myproject but only properties 1,2,3
    return new { property1 = "asdf", property2 = "123", property3 = "aaa" };
}
```

Comment: This looks like the closest to what I'm trying to do, I will try to implement it now and update answer.

Comment: Honestly, unless you have a bajillion webservice methods to maintain, I think you'd be better off defining static service contracts that are validated at compile time. It prevents accidental or impulsive changes that break the communication contract. Furthermore, you must always be mindful of _which methods return what_ when you (or others!) are maintaining them instead of having a self-documenting and self-validating API. You can always employ helper libraries (like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)) to help convert to/from the data transfer types.

Comment: Create good unittest and integration tests to validate your contracts. DTO can change as easily as dynamics if your sloppy.
Personally I would go for DTO's for each outcome and use unittests in combination with integration tests.

Comment: This answer is the way I chose to go. Please note that while this is the best solution for me and my particular constraints in my project, that it is not the only solution, and I recommend anyone who has a similar problem to check out the lengthy discussions in comments as there is a lot of good information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the code that consumes this object, you could do away with the attributes you mention (presumably properties?), and replace them with a `Dictionary` containing attribute name/value pairs.

Then, just populate it with the required values at constructor time.

Answer (score 1):

If a property has a Null value it will be skipped when the object is serialized to Json. So one possible solution would be to use nullable properties.

Comment: The issue is that these properties are not null in the object, they still have data in them, it is just not specifically relevant to that function. I suppose I could set each non-relevant property to null before returning, but I feel like there is a better way to do this